# IOS - how to retrieve image path from SQLite and show it in UIamgeView

Tags: ios, database, image, sqlite, path

I have an SQLite database with an image column that i store image paths in it, and I attached the images in the project folder.

Now I want to retrieve these image paths and show the images in UImageView
How can I do that using objective-c?

Comment: Can you not just store all images in one folder and have only image name in Sqlite? You will have same path for all of them.

Comment: yes I can, but my question is how to use sql query to retrieve these images from the database

Comment: If you are not using CoreData you should check this tutorial  http://www.raywenderlich.com/913/sqlite-tutorial-for-ios-making-our-app

Comment: Thank you. But the tutorial doesn't answer my question. I know how to retrieve text and numbers. What I want is how to retrieve image path then set an UImageView with that image.

Comment: Image path is presented as text in DB. You can then use [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:yourPath]

Answer (score 2):

Suppose in your Project Folder, You have 3 Images like a.png, b.png and c.png and You are save imagePath like this.

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"a" ofType:@"png"]
```

we are getting imagePath from Database like below:

```
NSString *strImagePath = @"/var/mobile/Applications/BCFC4543-85BD-4B3D-8334-E4B6A05BA2E9/Test.app/a.png";

UIImage *aImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:strImagePath];

aImageView.image = aImage;
```

It's working Fine.